# Do declared variables in a recursive statement create a new variable, or refresh the original one?

Tags: java, string, recursion

```
public void readLine(int startAt){
    int i = input.indexOf("(",startAt);

    if(i!=-1){
        readLine(i+1);
    }
}
```

"input" is a string that should be an equation like:

12 + 8 * 2^(1/4) + 2 / (2 * 7) + ( 5 * (1/2) )

when you call on the statement, which in this case should always be "readLine(0);"
it will set an integer 'i' to the first location it finds a "(" at. The if statement checks to see if the integer came back with anything (-1 means no "(" was found). So if it found a "(" then it would run the method again but the argument would be the index in the string of the "(" it found plus one. and The recursion would continue until it can't find any more "(". and i would be the last occurance of "(" in the string

Comment: Is this not working in some way?  What exactly are you asking?

Comment: Recursive calls don't share variables.

Comment: So when there are no more parentheses, the calculation stops?

Comment: Each recursive call creates a new "instance" of the variable. Here is a nice lecture that explains it in detail. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=341VqGbPFk8

Answer (score 2):

They create new variables. Each recursive call has its own set of variables. For each call new set of variables is pushed on the stack. When call ends variables are popped off the stack (LIFO - last in, first out).

Comment: You should elaborate, mentioning about passing arguments by value. Now answer is correct, but it doesn't explain why this happens.

Comment: How arguments are passed is not particularly relevant here. The magic word is "stack": for each call, a new set of local variables is allallocated on the stack.

Comment: One extra bit; in Java, they create the shallowest possible copy.

Answer (score 0):

The test you might want to try is this:

```
int x = 1;
int y = 2;
swap(x, y);
System.out.println("x:" + x);
System.out.println("y:" + y);
```

You'd have to write something to do the swap.

And it may work different for primitives (int) than it does for things that extend Object (Integer), and differently for arrays of those objects.